# Сетевой мост и виртуальная машина

Tags: сеть

Имеется linux машина, подключенная одним из сетевых адаптеров к интернету. Если я поставлю на нее kvm, подключу к ней этот адаптер в режиме моста, а затем полностью закрою на хост-машине все входящие порты. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в таком случае трафик все равно будет идти в виртуальную машину?

Вопрос связан с желанием перенести существующий роутер pfsense с физической машины на нее же, но в виде виртуалки.

И еще один наивный вопрос: сейчас роутер получает ip от провайдера по dhcp. После переноса его в виртуалку и подключения по мосту, получится что к сети провайдера подключено фактически два сетевых адаптера - физический и виртуальный. Я что-то вообще не понимаю что из этого выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, трафик будет проходить. По определению, цепочка INPUT применяется к пакетам, предназначенным *«этой»* машине. Виртуалка — не «эта». FORWARD применяется в процессе маршрутизации. У вас мост — маршрутизации нет.
2. Правильный подход — разделить VLAN'ами. Например, VLAN1 — LAN, VLAN2 — uplink. Далее выдаёте со свитча в сторону хост-машины первый и второй вланы с тэгами. На хост-машине создаёте eth0.1 и eth0.2. eth0 оставляете вообще без IP-адреса. На eth0.1 вешаете адрес из локальной сети (ну, она же у вас должна быть видна из локалки?) и мост. На eth0.2 вешаете только мост. Цепляете внутренний интерфейс виртуального роутера к мосту на eth0.1 хоста, а внешний — к мосту на eth0.2. На порту свитча, смотрящем в сторону провайдера, прописываете только VLAN2 без тэга. Всё. К сети провайдера подключён только виртуальный порт.

Продумываемая вами схема — вполне рабочая, но есть некоторые тонкости. Например, в момент перезагрузки хоста на нём могут не подниматься некоторые службы (у меня чудит ntp) и наблюдаться проблемы с получением адреса по DHCP, потому что во время их инициализации default gateway ещё только-только начинает загружаться, соответственно, недоступен DNS и DHCP (если он на этом самом default gateway).